# Are Play form JSON parsers filtering out empty arrays incorrectly?

Tags: scala, playframework

In a PUT request from a client device, I would like the application/json body to look like `{"content": []}` in order to clear a list I'm maintaining for the client. However, in a Play Form such key-value pair where the value is an empty array disappears after form parsing.

You can see that in regular (non-Form) Play JSON parsing, the empty array is maintained as expected.

```
[info] Starting scala interpreter...
Welcome to Scala 2.11.12 (OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM, Java 1.8.0_212).
Type in expressions for evaluation. Or try :help.

scala> import play.api.libs.json._
import play.api.libs.json._

scala> val json = Json.parse("""{"content": []}""")
json: play.api.libs.json.JsValue = {"content":[]}
```

However, in Play's form parsing, the behavior is different.

```
private[data] object FormUtils {
  def fromJson(prefix: String = "", js: JsValue): Map[String, String] = js match {
    case JsObject(fields) =>
      val prefix2 = Option(prefix).filterNot(_.isEmpty).map(_ + ".").getOrElse("")
      fields.iterator
        .map { case (key, value) => fromJson(prefix2 + key, value) }
        .foldLeft(Map.empty[String, String])(_ ++ _)
    case JsArray(values) =>
      values.zipWithIndex.iterator
        .map { case (value, i) => fromJson(s"$prefix[$i]", value) }
        .foldLeft(Map.empty[String, String])(_ ++ _)
    case JsNull           => Map.empty
    case JsUndefined()    => Map.empty
    case JsBoolean(value) => Map(prefix -> value.toString)
    case JsNumber(value)  => Map(prefix -> value.toString)
    case JsString(value)  => Map(prefix -> value.toString)
  }
}
```

https://github.com/playframework/playframework/blob/826c76ee967d8ec35b76b9a8b594bfaa676a9510/core/play/src/main/scala/play/api/data/Form.scala#L397

The general idea of the function is a recursive traversal of the incoming JSValue objects and arrays where null, undefined, booleans, numbers, strings, and empty objects and arrays serve as base cases.

In the JsArray case, if `values` is empty then it returns `Map.empty[String, String]`. As a result, both `[]` and `{"content": []}` will be parsed to `Map.empty[String, String]`. For a form, the `[]` case seems reasonable, but `{"content": []}` is a legitimate key-value pair that should be kept in the form. Note that the same issue occurs with an empty JsObject.

Does this seem like a reasonable issue? If so, any workarounds that you can think of? I understand that it could be difficult for Play to change this since users of the framework might already be depending on this behavior.

Answer (score 0):

I think that is correct behavior, since as far as forms are concerned there is no concept of an Array.

A form simply consists of a set of key-value-pairs and an array is just flattened to fit into this scheme, a la `path.to.array[0] = value`.

The form, however, can then be mapped to a model which actually has a sequence of values.